# python3 correct argv usage

Tags: dictionary, python-3.x, command, argv

Here is the code I have for reading a text file a storing it as a dictionary:

```
from sys import argv

def data(file):
    d = {}
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() != '':
            key,value = line.split(":")
            if key == 'RootObject':
                continue
            if key == 'Object':
                obj = value.strip()
                d[obj]={}
            else:
                d[obj][key] = value.strip()
    return d

file = open(argv[1])
planets = data(file)
print(planets)
```

My question is did I implement the `argv` correctly so that any user can run the dictionary by just typing `solardictionary.py random.txt` in the commandline and run it. I tried running this but I keep getting an index error and I'm not sure there might be something wrong with my `argv` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type `file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')` in order to access the array because it is contained within the `sys` module.

http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#module-sys

You may also be interested in opening the file within a try-catch block.

Comment: ohhh Ok yea that makes sense. Thanks! @Alex_W I could use A try block although I'm not very familiar with it. But I think your solution may fix my problem.